# scss file saved but not updating homepage

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass

I am running into some problem about updating my front page. The scss file is saved only it won't update my background color. It is in a file called full-width-split.scss. I also have a file called style-index.css in the build folder of the WordPress website. I don't know why it isn't updating my background color even though the scss file is saved. How do I solve this issue?

Inspect shows this:

```
  @include atMedium {
    display: flex;
  }

  &__one {
    flex: 1;
    padding: 1.6rem 16px;
    @include atMedium {
      padding: 40px;
    }

    .full-width-split__inner {
      @include atMedium {
        float: right;
      }
    }
  }

  &__two {
    flex: 1;
    background-color: $beige;
    padding: 1.6rem 16px;
    @include atMedium {
      padding: 40px;
    }
  }

  &__inner {
    @media (min-width: 1350px) {
      width: 610px;
    }
  }
}
```

But it needs to show this:

```
.full-width-split {
  @include atMedium {
    display: flex;
  }

  &__one {
    flex: 1;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    padding: 1.6rem 16px;
    @include atMedium {
      padding: 40px;
    }

    .full-width-split__inner {
      @include atMedium {
        float: right;
      }
    }
  }

  &__two {
    flex: 1;
    background-color: #faf0ca;
    padding: 1.6rem 16px;
    @include atMedium {
      padding: 40px;
    }
  }

  &__inner {
    @media (min-width: 1350px) {
      width: 610px;
    }
  }
}



  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IAO6k.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/leSek.png
```

Comment: In the SCSS code you provided, you are missing `background-color` inside the `&__one` selector. But you have `background-color: #ffffff;` in the CSS. Another issue might be caching. You should look into using cache-busting on your CSS file to make sure the site always has the latest styles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're only saving the scss file and aren't actually generating the css from it - You have to actually build/compile the css from your scss. This can be done in a variety of ways depending on your working process, the tools you use, etc.

You can build it using [terminal/CLI](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/cli/dart-sass), a taskrunner such as [gulp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-sass) or [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/sass-loader/), or easily using a [plugin for your code editor](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=glenn2223.live-sass).

Once one of these tools has generated the .css files from your .scss, then you'll have stylesheets which the browser can actually see and utilise (provided you've generated them in the right place in your folder structure).

Comment: You are right. It was only saving what was in the scss file and not the css file. There was an empty line of code in the style-index.css file, so I added the background color to the style-index.css file with VS code and it added it to the webpage. Your answer worked for me! Thank you so much!!